# creating a string concatenation that sorts names and age into groups

Tags: java

this is an assignment from an online java class I've been taking on my own time in order to improve and I'm now stuck on this par I've been trying to do this for days this is the progressive gotten.it needs me to create a string concatenation Any advice or tips would be nice I am still very new to java coding and I hope to improve

the objective for the assignment is that there is a bunch of names that need to be sorted at the graveyards here are some examples *there are too many on the note to include all of them

John William ALLARDYCE   17 Mar 1844 2.9  Little Knight Ryder Street
Frederic Alex. ALLARDYCE 21 Apr 1844 0.17 Little Knight Ryder Street
Philip AMIS              03 Aug 1848 1    18 1/2 Knight Rider Street
Thomas ANDERSON          06 Jul 1845 27   2, Bennet's Hill

***Example Input***
John William ALLARDYCE   17 Mar 1844 2.9  Little Knight Ryder Street
Frederic Alex. ALLARDYCE 21 Apr 1844 0.7  Little Knight Ryder Street
Philip AMIS              03 Aug 1848 1    18 1/2 Knight Rider Street
Thomas ANDERSON          06 Jul 1845 27   2, Bennet's Hill
Edward ANGEL             20 Nov 1842 22   Crane Court Lambeth Hill
Lucy Ann COLEBACK        23 Jul 1843 14w  Lambeth Hill
Thomas William COLLEY    08 Aug 1833 4d   Lambeth Hill
Joseph COLLIER           03 Apr 1831 58   Lambeth Hill

**Example Output (using only the Example Input above)**
In the St. Mary Magdelene Old Fish Cemetery -->
Name of youngest person: Thomas William COLLEY
Age of youngest person: 0.011
Name of oldest person: Joseph COLLIER
Age of oldest person: 58.0
the code below is the original parts

```
package Cemetery;

/**
* Module 5 Project: Cemetery
*
* Name: 
* 
* AP Computer Science, Virtual Virginia
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Cemetery
{
//////// MAIN ////////
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  File file = new File("cemetery.txt");
  int numEntries = countEntries(file);
  Person[] cemetery = readIntoArray(file, numEntries); 
  
  //TESTING ONLY: un-comment the 2 lines below to see if array was created properly
  //for (int i = 0; i < cemetery.length; i++) 
    //System.out.println(cemetery[i].getName() + " " + cemetery[i].getAge());
  
  int min = locateMinAgePerson(cemetery);
  int max = locateMaxAgePerson(cemetery); 
  System.out.println("In the St. Mary Magdelene Old Fish Cemetery --> ");
  System.out.println("Name of youngest person: " + cemetery[min].getName());
  System.out.println("Age of youngest person: " + cemetery[min].getAge());    
  System.out.println("Name of oldest person: " + cemetery[max].getName());
  System.out.println("Age of oldest person: " + cemetery[max].getAge());     
  }

  //////// METHODS (Cemetery) ////////

  /* Counts and returns the number of entries in File f.
  * Uses a try-catch block.   
  * @param f -- the file object
  */
  public static int countEntries(File f)
  {
   int i = 0;
   try
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
       while (scan.hasNextLine())
       {
           i++;
           scan.nextLine();
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("Check filename.");
   }
   
   return i;
   }

   /* Reads the data.
   * Fills the array with Person objects.
   * Uses a try-catch block.   
   * @param f -- the file object 
   *        num -- the number of lines in the File f  
   */
   public static Person[] readIntoArray (File f, int num)
   {

   }

   /* A helper method that instantiates one Person object.
   * @param entry -- one line of the input file.
   */
   private static Person makePerson(String entry)
   {
   String currentName = entry.substring(0,25);
   String currentBurialDate = //write code here!
   String currentAge = //write code here!
   return new Person(currentName, currentBurialDate, currentAge);
   }  

  /* Finds and returns the location (the index) of the Person
  * who is the youngest.
  * @param arr -- an array of Person objects.
  */
  public static int locateMinAgePerson(Person[] arr)
  {

  }   

  /* Finds and returns the location (the index) of the Person
  who is the oldest.
  @param arr -- an array of Person objects.
  */
  public static int locateMaxAgePerson(Person[] arr)
  {

  }         
  }

  class Person 
  {
  //// FIELDS ////

  /* Declare fields for the name, the burial date, and the age. */
  
  ////// CONSTRUCTOR //////

  /* @param n -- a String representing a name from the input file.
  *        bd -- a String representing a burial date from the input file.
  *        a -- a String representing an age from the input file.
  */
  public Person(String n, String bd, String a)
  {
   name = n;
   burialDate = bd;
   age = calculateAge(a);
  }

  //////// METHODS (Person) ////////

  /* Calculates the numerical equivalent of an age in String format.
  * If the String contains a "w" (weeks) or "d" (days), calculates appropriate portion
  * of a year.
  @param a -- a String representing a person's age.
  */
  public double calculateAge(String a)
  {
   double numericalAge;
   if(a.contains("w"))
   {
       int pos = a.indexOf("w");
       double numWeeks = Double.parseDouble(a.substring(0,pos));
       numericalAge = numWeeks/52.0;
   }
   else if(a.contains("d"))
   {
       //write code here!
   }
   else
   {
       //write code here!
   }
   return numericalAge;
   }

   ////////// ACCESSOR METHODS (Person) //////////
```

/* Write 3 accessor methods for the fields of the Person class.
* (See the main method in the Cemetery class.)
*/

```
}
```

***The code below is what I wrote***

```
 /**
 * Module 5 Project: Cemetery
 *
 * Name: 
 * 
 * AP Computer Science, Virtual Virginia
 */
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class Cemetery
 {
 //////// MAIN ////////
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
  File file = new File("cemetery.txt");
  int numEntries = countEntries(file);
  Person[] cemetery = readIntoArray(file, numEntries); 
  
  //TESTING ONLY: un-comment the 2 lines below to see if array was created properly
  //for (int i = 0; i < cemetery.length; i++) 
    //System.out.println(cemetery[i].getName() + " " + cemetery[i].getAge());
  
  int min = locateMinAgePerson(cemetery);
  int max = locateMaxAgePerson(cemetery); 
  System.out.println("In the St. Mary Magdelene Old Fish Cemetery --> ");
  System.out.println("Name of youngest person: " + cemetery[min].getName());
  System.out.println("Age of youngest person: " + cemetery[min].getAge());    
  System.out.println("Name of oldest person: " + cemetery[max].getName());
  System.out.println("Age of oldest person: " + cemetery[max].getAge());     
  }

  //////// METHODS (Cemetery) ////////

 /* Counts and returns the number of entries in File f.
 * Uses a try-catch block.   
 * @param f -- the file object
 */
 public static int countEntries(File f)
 {
   int i = 0;
   try
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
       while (scan.hasNextLine())
       {
           i++;
           scan.nextLine();
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println("Check filename.");
   }
   
   return i;
}

 /* Reads the data.
 * Fills the array with Person objects.
 * Uses a try-catch block.   
 * @param f -- the file object 
 *        num -- the number of lines in the File f  
 */
public static Person[] readIntoArray (File f, int num)
{

}

/* A helper method that instantiates one Person object.
* @param entry -- one line of the input file.
*/
private static Person makePerson(String entry)
{
   String currentName = entry.substring(0,25);
   String currentBurialDate = //write code here!
   String currentAge = //write code here!
   return new Person(currentName, currentBurialDate, currentAge);
}  

/* Finds and returns the location (the index) of the Person
* who is the youngest.
* @param arr -- an array of Person objects.
*/
public static int locateMinAgePerson(Person[] arr)
{
   
   for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)   
    {  
        for (int j = i + 1; j < total; j++)   
        {  
            if (a[i] > a[j])   
            {  
                temp = a[i];  
                a[i] = a[j];  
                a[j] = temp;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
   return a[0];  
}
public static void main(String args[]){  
    int a[]={1,2,5,6,3,2};  
    System.out.println("Smallest: "+getSmallest(a,6));  
}   

/* Finds and returns the location (the index) of the Person
  who is the oldest.
  @param arr -- an array of Person objects.
*/
 public static int locateMaxAgePerson(Person[] arr)
 {
 
 }        
 }

 class Person
 {
 //// FIELDS ////

 /* Declare fields for the name, the burial date, and the age. */
   
 ////// CONSTRUCTOR //////
 
 /* @param n -- a String representing a name from the input file.
 *        bd -- a String representing a burial date from the input file.
 *        a -- a String representing an age from the input file.
 */
 public Person(String n, String bd, String a)
 {
   name = n;
   burialDate = bd;
   age = calculateAge(a);
 }

 //////// METHODS (Person) ////////

 /* Calculates the numerical equivalent of an age in String format.
 * If the String contains a "w" (weeks) or "d" (days), calculates appropriate portion
 * of a year.
  @param a -- a String representing a person's age.
*/
public double calculateAge(String a)
{
   double numericalAge;
   if(a.contains("w"))
   {
       int pos = a.indexOf("w");
       double numWeeks = Double.parseDouble(a.substring(0,pos));
       numericalAge = numWeeks/52.0;
   }
   else if(a.contains("d"))
   {
       //write code here!
   }
   else
   {
       //write code here!
   }
   return numericalAge;
 }

 ////////// ACCESSOR METHODS (Person) //////////

 /* Write 3 accessor methods for the fields of the Person class.
 * (See the main method in the Cemetery class.)
 */

 }
```

***What I am currently trying to fix***

```
 class Person
 {
 //// FIELDS ////

 /* Declare fields for the name, the burial date, and the age. */
   
 ////// CONSTRUCTOR //////
 
 /* @param n -- a String representing a name from the input file.
 *        bd -- a String representing a burial date from the input file.
 *        a -- a String representing an age from the input file.
 */
 public Person(String n, String bd, String a)
 {
   name = n;
   burialDate = bd;
   age = calculateAge(a);
 }

 //////// METHODS (Person) ////////

 /* Calculates the numerical equivalent of an age in String format.
 * If the String contains a "w" (weeks) or "d" (days), calculates appropriate portion
 * of a year.
  @param a -- a String representing a person's age.
*/
public double calculateAge(String a)
{
   double numericalAge;
   if(a.contains("w"))
   {
       int pos = a.indexOf("w");
       double numWeeks = Double.parseDouble(a.substring(0,pos));
       numericalAge = numWeeks/52.0;
   }
   else if(a.contains("d"))
   {
       //write code here!
   }
   else
   {
       //write code here!
   }
   return numericalAge;
 }
```

Comment: i'm confused on how the data is parsed... Can you explain each piece of a line of input from the example input?

Comment: I am having a bit problem understanding what you want to achieve in the `age` part. Explain in terms of Input and Output. Please also explain how should the `calculateAge(String age)` method work.

Comment: so the input is the names, addresses, and information of people the output should be. In the St. Mary Magdelene Old Fish Cemetery --> Name of youngest person:and then the information after that